# When you define a read function for a kernel module, where does the function's arguments come when it is called?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Let's say I have a kernel module named "hello".

For example:

```
static struct file_operations hello_fops = {
        .open = hello_open,
        .read = hello_read,
        .release = hello_release,
};
```

```
static ssize_t hello_read(struct file *f, char *buf, size_t len, loff_t *offset){
       // some code here
}
```

When you read from the `/dev/hello` character device file, the `hello_read` function will be called, but where do the function's arguments come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arguments come from the system call which causes the read:

- a program calls [`read`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html), passing it the file descriptor, pointer to a buffer, and count;
- the system call is [handled by `ksys_read`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15.6/source/fs/read_write.c#L612), which determines the `struct file` corresponding to the file descriptor, and the current position in the file, before [calling `vfs_read`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15.6/source/fs/read_write.c#L623);
- `vfs_read` [calls the relevant `struct file_operations`’ `read` function](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15.6/source/fs/read_write.c#L483).

There’s a similar path starting from [`pread`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pread.2.html), which additionally provides the file position to read from; it is [handled by `ksys_pread64`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15.6/source/fs/read_write.c#L662).